# C++: incomplete type named in nested name specifier

Tags: c++

I am trying to resolve a circular dependency in my c++ project and based on other answers here on StackOverflow, I followed the same methodology. However, I am still seeing an issue:

This is my code snippet below:

```
// In ip6.hh
namespace net
{
    class Inet4;

      /** IP6 layer */
      class IP6
      {
         using Stack = class Inet4;

         void set_packet_forwarding(Stack::Forward_delg fwd)
         { forward_packet_ = fwd; }

         Stack& stack_;
     }
}

// In Inet4.hpp
#include "ip6/ip6.hpp" 
namespace net {

  class Inet4 : public Inet<IP4>{

  IP6& ip_obj()
  { return ip6_; }

   IP6    ip6_;
  }
}
```

In main.cpp, I am including it as follows:

```
#include <net/ip6/ip6.hpp>
#include <net/inet4.hpp>
```

> ```
> > /home/nikhil/projects/ipv6/IncludeOS/api/net/ip6/ip6.hpp:84:32: error:
> > incomplete type 'net::Inet4' named in nested name specifier
> >     void set_packet_forwarding(Stack::Forward_delg fwd)
> >                                ^~~~~~~ /home/nikhil/projects/ipv6/IncludeOS/api/net/ip6/ip6.hpp:35:9: note:
> > forward declaration of 'net::Inet4'   class Inet4;
> ```

Comment: What is the `Forward_delg`? I don't see it declared anywhere in the code.

Comment: I've removed that bit from the snippet

Comment: Can you add it back? It seems like an important part of the question.

Comment: Would have to add a lot more then: For ex, this is what it is:

 
    using Forward_delg  = delegate<void(IP_packet_ptr, Stack& source, Conntrack::Entry_ptr)>;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is only Inet decalaration (not definition). Compiler does not know definition of Inet4 (hence Stack which is alaised to Inet4).

Comment: Inet4 is defined in inet4.hpp and included later in cpp file. How should I fix this?

Comment: you could reverse ipv6 and inet4 as you can forward declare ipv6 and you do not access any member or function of ip6 within defnition of inet4

Comment: Can I not do that for inet? and make sure ipv6 doesn't access any member function on inet?
Also, for ex: In my ip6 class, I have this as well: 
Stack::Forward_delg forward_packet_;